# Is there a concise analytical solution to this system of polynomial equations?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have a system of equations given by 
$$\frac{n_1^3}{3}-\frac{n_1^2}{\mu}+\frac{1}{3k_1}=0 \\
\frac{n_2^3}{3}-\frac{n_2^2}{\mu}+\frac{1}{3k_2}=0 \\
\vdots \\
\frac{n_i^3}{3}-\frac{n_i^2}{\mu}+\frac{1}{3k_i}=0 \\
n_1+n_2+...+n_i=N
$$

where the $k$'s and the $N$ are known, while the $\mu$ and the $n$'s are unknown. I believe that I could solve for the unknowns by using Buchberger's algorithm to find a Groebner Basis, but that gets messy fast. Is there some way to simplify this problem so that a Groebner Basis is not needed and I can find a more manageable analytical solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the $i$ cubic equations and express the $n_i$ as a function of $\mu$. Then the last identity gives you a single equation in $\mu$.

If you are unlucky, the cubics can have three real solutions, for a possible total of $3^i$. This means that if the problem can be reduced to a univariate polynomial, it will be of degree at least $3^i$, not really concise.

The little monster is

$$\sum_{j=1}^i\left(\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{l_j^2-2l_j\nu^3}-l_j+\nu^3}+\sqrt[3]{-\sqrt{l_j^2-2l_j\nu^3}-l_j+\nu^3}+\nu\right)=N$$

where we used $l_j:=1/{2k_j}$ and $\nu=1/\mu$, for convenience.

If $l_j<2\nu^3$, the $j^{th}$ equation has three real roots.